# I am trying to find $C > 0$ such that for all $n \ge 11$ we have $n^4 + 100 n^2 + 50 \le C n^4$.

Tags: calculus, algorithms, asymptotics

Sorry, it might be the silly question, But I want to find $C > 0$ such that for all $n \ge 11$ we have $n^4 + 100 n^2 + 50 \le C n^4$. How to derive it?

Comment: This function has no upper bound.

Comment: @Malik: My guess is that you have not provided all of the information, else this function has no upper bound. Are you sure you provided everything?

Comment: @ajotatxe, Then How author has written answers n0 = 11?

Comment: @Moo , f(n) = n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= c.g(n) .. this is full form of question. I think My posted question also make sense.

Comment: What is $g(n)$?

Comment: @Malik it makes no sense. Here check this out https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(n)%3Dn%5E4%2B100n%5E2%2B50

Comment: @Malik: your questions makes no sense. What are $c$ and $g(n)$?

Comment: $f(n) = g(n^2)$, where $g(u) = u^2 + 100 u + 50 = (u + 50)^2 -2450$. I cannot see any relation between $n = 11$ and any sort of max or min for this. (I'm just guessing here that the hint might have involved this particular trick --- noticing it's a function of $n^2$ --- and have been transcribed erroneously).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is gibberish

Comment: @Malik Are you trying to find $C > 0$ such that for all $n \ge 11$ we have $n^4 + 100 n^2 + 50 \le C n^4$? This is the only way I can make sense of what you have written. Please edit the question before it gets closed.

Comment: @AlexVong yes, man this is what I am asking for. Thanks

Comment: What, if one divides both sides by n^4 and tries with worst possible case then C ≥ 151!

Comment: @Edumaths555 why worst ?? why not best which n0=11?

Answer (score 1):

$n^4 + 100 n^2 + 50 \le n^4 + 100 n^4 + 50 n^4 = 151 n^4$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$. So $C=151$ works.

If you want to find the smallest $C$ that works for $n\ge 11$, you need to maximise $g(n)=\dfrac{n^4 + 100 n^2 + 50}{n^4}$ for $n \ge 11$. You'll get $C=g(11)$ because $g$ is decreasing.

Comment: this is worst case. How to get tight upper bound which is n0=11 ??

Comment: Your question did not mention the need for the smallest $C$.

Comment: @Ihf, I know about results C to meet the condition, but what's about best inputs n0? n0=11 is needed. How to do it? This is the best case of Big O for this function.

Comment: Find g(11) from lhf's solution, that will work as the function g(n) is decreasing.